# How to use driver.getWindowHandle() in Java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application which triggers pop up window in same parent Web page and have to perform some operations in pop up window. How to handle this kind of situation in selenium java?

I have tried with driver.getWindowHandles() method but it does not switch control to pop up window.

Comment: Is it an alert or popup?

Comment: it's pop up(Modal dialog box) of angular JS. I've tried with driver.switchTo().activeElement as well but no luck.

Comment: hmm. Is it a public url? if not do you have any sample url where we can simulate the same behavior?